# numpy.where produces inconsistent results

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a piece of code where I need to look for an index of a value in a numpy array.
For this task, I use numpy.where.
The problem is that numpy.where produces a wrong result, i.e. returns an empty array, in situations where I am certain that the searched value is in the array.
To make things worse, I tested that the element is really in the array with a for loop, and in case it is found, also look for it with numpy.where.
Oddly enough, then it finds a result, while literally a line later, it doesnt.

Here is how the code looks like:

```
# progenitors, descendants and progenitor_outputnrs are 2D-arrays that are filled from reading in files.
# outputnrs is a 1d-array.

ozi = 0
for i in range(descendants[ozi].shape[0]):
    if descendants[ozi][i] > 0:

        if progenitors[ozi][i] < 0:
            oind = outputnrs[0] - progenitor_outputnrs[ozi][i] - 1
            print "looking for prog", progenitors[ozi][i], "with outputnr", progenitor_outputnrs[ozi][i], "in", outputnrs[oind]

            for p in progenitors[oind]:
                if p == -progenitors[ozi][i]:
# the following line works...
                    print "found", p, np.where(progenitors[oind]==-progenitors[ozi][i])[0][0]
# the following line doesn't!
            iind = np.where(progenitors[oind]==-progenitors[ozi][i])[0][0]
```

I get the output:

```
looking for prog -76 with outputnr 65 in 66
found 76 79
looking for prog -2781 with outputnr 65 in 66
found 2781 161
looking for prog -3797 with outputnr 63 in 64
found 3797 163
looking for prog -3046 with outputnr 65 in 66
found 3046 163
looking for prog -6488 with outputnr 65 in 66
found 6488 306
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script.py", line 1243, in <module>
    main()
  File "script.py", line 974, in main
    iind = np.where(progenitors[oind]==-progenitors[out][i])[0][0]
IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0
```

I use python 2.7.12 and numpy 1.14.2.

Does anyone have an idea why this is happening?

Comment: `where(cond)` finds the true elements in `cond`.   If empty then `cond` is all false. Make sure the equality test is right.  Testing floats is tricky.

Comment: @hpaulj I use the exact same piece of code, `np.where(progenitors[oind]==-progenitors[ozi][i])[0][0]` in both the line that works and doesn't work. So once `cond` is satisfied, a line later is all false. Furthermore, those are integer arrays.

Comment: You have to _indent_ the last line to be able to affirm that "the same line is executed below", since the upper line runs only when that `if` is true, while the last line executes even when it's false.

Comment: @heltonbiker Fair enough, I did that, still same error message at same point.

Comment: It would be easier to help you if you provided a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that could be run by just copying it to a file and running it.  That is, create a self-contained runnable script with sample data that demonstrates the problem.  (There's a good chance you'll find the problem on your own if you do that!)